# Select only today date validation in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

This is my code for bootstrap datepicker.

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thanks for all to help me. Here is the updated fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5sfr0g36/5/

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minDate` and `maxDate` properties to `new Date()`;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(),

 });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Azola but its not working, and you have error of comma(,) in last line.

Comment: Hey Azola! You are using datetimepicker() and i am using datepicker(). So it make difference ;)